# How can I import a SVN-diff to GIT?

Tags: git, svn, import, bitbucket

I hope I can put my question here without being bashed for any reason.

I moved a subversion repository to git (bitbucket) and anything works fine. Now some users committed there changes into the old svn-repository.

Now I created a svn-dump for the missing revisions and don't know how to import that into git. The 'git svn clone'-command is how I understand it only for complete dumps!?

What command do I need for the import without destroying new new git-repro?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not on a windows OS:

```
git svn clone ${svn_url} tmpdir
cd tmpdir
git format-patch ${start_rev}..${end_rev}
patch_dir=`pwd`
cd ${git_repo_dir}
git am ${patch_dir}/*.patch
rm -rf ${patch_dir}
```

Comment: That sounds very good. Does those patches contain also new and binary files and the comment the user left with the commit?

Comment: It does add files, I believe it preserves binary and does use the users comment (including their name).